# Count the number of different strings in a single line using UNIX command

Tags: unix

I am looking for a solution to count the number of occurrences of different strings in a single line using unix commands.

Say, I have a file x.log and the contents within the file are:

```
2013.12.25 Can you provide me a solution to the question
Hello World how are you
2013.12.25 Can I ask a question
2013.12.26 Can you provide me a solution to the question
Hello World how are you
2013.12.26 Can I ask a question
```

The command should count the number of occurrences of the strings "Can" and "question" and provide me the output

```
2013.12.25 4
2013.12.26 4
```

Comment: Are the lines in x.log already sorted by the first field?

Comment: Yes, they are written according to the date.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < file | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

The `tr` converts all spaces into newlines. This will give you one word per line. Then we sort it and pipe it though uniq to get a frequency count and finally, we sort by frequencies.

Comment: I've updated the answer but I really think the whole thing is self explanatory to someone who's familiar with basic UNIX and willing to read the manual pages for the commands in the pipeline.

Comment: Downvote removed (as promised). If everyone knew "basic UNIX", this question wouldn't have been asked and therefore no answer would have been necessary, right? So clearly asking the question (and posting an answer to it) should be intended for those who *don't know basic UNIX*. :-) Also, see this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196187/172661)

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is a good fit for queries like this.

- for each line in the first file (using the NR==FNR idiom), the script stores the word (I assume one word per line) as one of the indexes of the `wordlist` array.
- for each line in the second file, it increments the `count` array (indexed by the first field of each line) for each field (excluding the first field, of course) that matches any word in `wordlist`.
- at the end, it prints out the `count` array

[I looked at your unedited question to verify that each Hello World line was actually supposed to be part of the previous line.]

```
$ cat wordlist
Can
question
$ cat x.log
2013.12.25 Can you provide me a solution to the question Hello World how are you
2013.12.25 Can I ask a question
2013.12.26 Can you provide me a solution to the question Hello World how are you
2013.12.26 Can I ask a question
$ cat count.awk 
{    if (NR == FNR) {
        wordlist[$1]
    } else {
        for (f=2; f<=NF; f++) {
            if ($f in wordlist) count[$1]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (c in count) {
        print c, count[c]
    }
}
$ awk -f count.awk wordlist x.log
2013.12.25 4
2013.12.26 4
```